# centralized and standard format to store some notification messages

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I want to store some notification messages (nearly 30 messages). 
Follows some rules that should be applied in the solution:
This will be shown to user in certain cases.

1. All messages should not be *hardcoded*.
2. What it the current standard format to store these kind of common messages outside of the source and access it in source.
3. This messages should be accessed anywhere in *C# MVC application* like controller, model, view as well as script.

I had 2 possibilities:

1. Stored in DB - But this will take more hit and more load if i get everytime. Because every page load we need to fetch some messages.
2. Stored in XML - By calling particular class from application start and get xml data and use throughout the mvc application.

Is these two possibilities are the only ones?

Please suggest me if there is any other efficient way to store and access these common messages.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is what resource files are for... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1820912/using-resx-files-for-global-application-messages/1821079#1821079

Comment: Dont know if MSMQ will fit your requirement, have a look; https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms711472(v=vs.85).aspx